# What are the individual rooms at a cinema called in British English?

Tags: british-english, cinema

In the US, we call the place we go to watch movies a "movie theater" and then if I were walking into one of the large rooms with the movie, I'd call it either the screen or the theater. For example, the movie is in theater 8 or on screen 8.

I know in the UK that the building is called a cinema, but what are the individual rooms called?

Comment: Also, US usage might have the overall building a "cineplex" or "multiplex"

Comment: The common term in the UK also is 'screen' (but always 'showing on screen 2' and signs showing 'Screen 2', never "I'm going into this screen").

Comment: Here in Australia we're more likely to use the British term for things than the American term. I would say "cinema", or possibly "theatre". The major cinema chain where I last saw a movie calls the individual theatres "cinemas": the email confirmation says the movie was in "cinemas 6" (the venue has 8 screens).

Answer (score 2):

Usually *screens*:

> Vue has 91 state of the art cinemas throughout the UK and Ireland,
>   with over 850 screens.

https://www.myvue.com/about-vue/about-us

*auditorium 1* or *house 1* might have been used in former times when cinemas only had one or two auditoria.